# Load an orphan cordova project in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I cloned a git project for cordova project that was made without VS.  There is no solution file.  There is no project file.  How can make an orphan cordova project visual studioized?

I know I can make a blank solution/project and add files to it.  But would that give me the debugging and all other features that comes with deving a cordova project?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use the new "Project from Existing Code" option in File -> New:

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: Works like a charm!  Thanks Michael!